# How to deploy a successful build using Travis CI and Scalr

Tags: jenkins, travis-ci, scalr

We're currently evaluating CI servers and Travis CI caught our eye since it is a hosted solution.  I haven't been able to find any information about it being able to deploy to Scalr though.  Has anyone had any luck setting this up?  I found information about using Jenkins to deploy to Scalr but I'd rather not go with Jenkins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying an application upon a Travis CI build success if functionally similar to deploying one upon a Jenkins success. All you need to do is to hook in to Scalr through its API when you build succeeds.

Using Travis CI, you can't really run arbitrary post-build shell scripts (unlike Jenkins). This makes integration a bit more complicated than using Jenkins (with Jenkins you just use the Scalr Command Line Tools to call the Scalr API), but it remains feasible.

All you need to do is [have Travis CI send a notification to a Webhook Endpoint](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#Webhook-notification) to a webapp you control (host that on your cloud infrastructure, or on e.g. Heroku), and have that webapp call the Scalr API.

---

Disclaimer: I work at Scalr.

Comment: Like I indicated in my answer, I work at Scalr. Feel free to let me know by email if you have extra questions (those may not be relevant to the wider SO audience). My email's thomas[at]scalr.com.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the input.  We thought that might be the case and ultimately decided to go with jenkins.  Would have been nice to keep things simple, but unfortunately it was just a little _too_ simple.

Comment: @AdamRitter, sounds good. Just ping me over email if you need any help with that.